# When coding Facebook likeability into a webpage, what are the drawbacks of using a simple "sharer.php" link without Open Graph tags and specification?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-opengraph

When coding a webpage you can, as I understand it, code Facebook likeability - defined as an element that when clicked takes a user somewhere that they can "like" the page on Facebook - by using a little "f" image (for example) as your link and the text `https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://foobar.com/mypage.html` as your hypertext reference ("href").

You can in addition refer to the Open Graph XML extension in the page's HTML declaration

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">,
```

which allows you to use meta tags to control the image that gets shown at Facebook and various other things.

Let's say that as far as Facebook is concerned all you want is for people who browse to your page to be able to "like" it on that company's website. If so, what are the drawbacks, if any, of doing no more than simply having a "sharer.php" link with an "f" image as your link?

Comment: The sharer script is for _sharing_ a link, it has rather little to do with actually _liking_ stuff (that would be the Like Button's job.) If you don't provide information about the content via OG meta tags, then Facebook will try and make an intelligent guess based on what your page contains. This data can possibly be shown in different places, where users might interact with the link.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't got a Facebook account, and I'm unfamiliar with a lot of what people do with them. But basically Facebook use the OG tags, if present, to gather what you tell them are important data about your page, and they only do it when one of their users decides to mention the page on their space at Facebook? I've no problems with that. I was wondering whether the tags might help Facebook find out whenever anyone browses to the site (the way that Google find out, for sites that use Google fonts), and it seems the answer is "no, they don't".